# Deep learning + Music , Music Generation using GAN , How to play songs from the midi images

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I am exploring to this repository : [musegan](https://github.com/salu133445/musegan) and tried to exectue it.

My shared [Google Colab Link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12Vw3-94YXbOKmNhuBh0TrKrgfZeOVmlQ)

​

It executes but i have no idea where do i get the generated music samples or how do i run the music.It produces bunch of `.png` images in the `./exp/`  folder but i don't know how is that helpful for generating music

​

even in the ReadMe file of this project the [Results](https://github.com/salu133445/musegan#sample-results) if you download it , it give bunch of images. I have no idea how can i use these images.

​

I am new to ML and Deep Learning, I picked this project because i have interest in music and i wanted to get inspired how deep learning will solve this problem.

​

i have read about ANN, RNN & CNN  and GAN but i am at a very noob level. But i want to learn this.

I did watch this video of project owner, [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SHPjZwSbRhs) But it's in Chinese , i did used [Google Translate (Chinese to English)](https://translate.google.com/?rlz=1C5CHFA_enIN831IN831&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&client=tw-ob#zh-TW/en/) to convert the audio into english text but it wasn't that great experience.

​

These are the slides :      [Slide 1](https://salu133445.github.io/bmusegan/pdf/bmusegan-ismir2018-slides.pdf)[Slide 2](https://salu133445.github.io/musegan/pdf/musegan-aaai2018-slides.pdf)

​

​

I know this is not the best first project to choose, but this is what interests me so i'll be more happy to invest my time to know about this project.

​

My background is in web-development both front-end & back-end.

​

Answer (score 1):

You need to look for the `.npz` files and convert them to midi format like this:

```
from pypianoroll import Multitrack

m = Multitrack('./test.npz')
m.write('./test.mid')
```

They have already answered your question in the repository's issues. Unfortunately, it's not on the documentation yet.